# How can I make the path element the same width of my svg element?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a chevron svg on my site but the positioning is making the page wider than I need it. So I was looking at the elements and noticed the path is much skinnier than the actual svg element.

[image: width of svg element]

[image: width of path element]

I want the width of the whole svg element to be only the width needed for the size of the chevron, I can supply the svg code.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 512.001 512.001" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512.001 512.001;" xml:space="preserve">
<path style="fill:#FFF;" d="M388.819,239.537L156.092,6.816c-9.087-9.089-23.824-9.089-32.912,0.002
    c-9.087,9.089-9.087,23.824,0.002,32.912l216.27,216.266L123.179,472.272c-9.087,9.089-9.087,23.824,0.002,32.912
    c4.543,4.544,10.499,6.816,16.455,6.816c5.956,0,11.913-2.271,16.457-6.817L388.819,272.45c4.366-4.364,6.817-10.283,6.817-16.455
    C395.636,249.822,393.185,243.902,388.819,239.537z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yeah it's there

Comment: I'm sorry you're right, I have added it now.

Answer (score 2):

You can just take `BBox` and redefine `viewBox` attribute by the data:

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
const path = svg.querySelector('path');

const box = path.getBBox();
svg.setAttribute('viewBox', `${box.x} ${box.y} ${box.width} ${box.height}`);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 512.001 512.001" style="background: gray; width: 100px">
    <path style="fill:#FFF;" d="M388.819,239.537L156.092,6.816c-9.087-9.089-23.824-9.089-32.912,0.002
    c-9.087,9.089-9.087,23.824,0.002,32.912l216.27,216.266L123.179,472.272c-9.087,9.089-9.087,23.824,0.002,32.912
    c4.543,4.544,10.499,6.816,16.455,6.816c5.956,0,11.913-2.271,16.457-6.817L388.819,272.45c4.366-4.364,6.817-10.283,6.817-16.455
    C395.636,249.822,393.185,243.902,388.819,239.537z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would either have to adjust the path to fit the current `viewbox` or adjust the viewbox to the current path.

The latter would be approximately like this:

```
viewBox="117 0 280 512.001"
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="117 0 280 512.001" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512.001 512.001;" xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M388.819,239.537L156.092,6.816c-9.087-9.089-23.824-9.089-32.912,0.002
    c-9.087,9.089-9.087,23.824,0.002,32.912l216.27,216.266L123.179,472.272c-9.087,9.089-9.087,23.824,0.002,32.912
    c4.543,4.544,10.499,6.816,16.455,6.816c5.956,0,11.913-2.271,16.457-6.817L388.819,272.45c4.366-4.364,6.817-10.283,6.817-16.455
    C395.636,249.822,393.185,243.902,388.819,239.537z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I would also change the enable-background accordingly  or deleted it all together. Also it would be nice to explain how did you get the new value for the viewBox,

Comment: Basically trial and error. I just adjusted the first value until it was right and then tweaked the other.